# How to mock the Context API nested Consumers in React to test?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React new Context API to manage our components state, the following is my basic code structure:

1. for each functional component, I have a Provider class to manage its state info. For example of EditFormCanvasProvider:

   ```
   class EditFormCanvasProvider extends React.Component<Props, State> {

       state = {
           controlsInfo: []
       }      

       render() {
           return (
               <EditFormCanvasContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                   {this.props.children}
               </EditFormCanvasContext.Provider>
           )
       }
   }

   export default EditFormCanvasProvider;
   ```
2. To consume the needed providers from other components, a consumers javascript file is created, the sample code is as follows:

   ```
   export default function FormBuilderConsumers(props) {
       const { children } = props;

       return (
           <FormBuilderContext.Consumer>
               {FormBuilder =>
                   <EditFormCanvasContext.Consumer>
                       {
                           EditFormCanvas => children({ FormBuilder, EditFormCanvas })
                       }
                   </EditFormCanvasContext.Consumer>
               }
           </FormBuilderContext.Consumer>
       )
   }
   ```
3. In the FormBuilder functional javascript component file, which consumes the FormBuilderConsumers. The code is as follows:

   ```
   const FormBuilder = () => {
       return (
           <FormBuilderConsumers>
               {(appData) =>
                   <div >
                       <Modal dismissible={true}                       
                           isOpen={appData.FormBuilder.modalIsOpen}
                           prompt={appData.FormBuilder.modalPrompt}
                           title={appData.EditFormCanvas.controlsInfo[0]}
                           size="medium"
                       >
                           <div>
                               {appData.FormBuilder.modalMessage}
                           </div>
                       </Modal>


                   </div>
               }
           </FormBuilderConsumers>
       )
   }
   export default FormBuilder;
   ```

I am trying to mock the FormBuiderConsumers in the FormBuilder to test the FormBuilder component By using Jest. But I don't know how to do it.

I am referencing these articles:

- https://medium.com/@wyattsweet/testing-react-components-using-the-new-context-api-a1c553edc2fa
- https://medium.com/@ryandrewjohnson/unit-testing-components-using-reacts-new-context-api-4a5219f4b3fe

but it seems they don't put multiple consumers into one file and export it to be consumed as what I am doing.

Comment: Can you add your test code to the question? Enzyme allows an optional context parameter, both in shallow and mount rendering, although I don't know if it works with the new API just yet

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need, and I simply mocked my appropriate Context Consumer to pass the mock data.

E.g. in your case, on your test file, something like:

```
import { EditFormCanvasContext } from '?';
import { mockEditFormCanvasContext } from '?';


EditFormCanvasContext.Consumer = jest.fn((props: any) => props.children({ ...mockEditFormCanvasContext }));
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! I will test your suggestion later.