# Testing destructured Context consumer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-context

I'm trying to test a component using Jest + Enzyme, making sure that a component was rendered as a child of my consumer. A similar test works when I do this:

```
    <FormContextConsumer>
      {({ ...props }) => (
        <Footer
          ...
        />
      )}
    </FormContextConsumer>
```

mock the context like so:

```
jest.mock("../../context/FormContext", () => ({
  FormContextConsumer: props => props.children()
}));
```

and test it like this:

```
it(`should render a 'Footer' component inside the 'FormContextConsumer'`, () => {
  expect(
    shallowTestComponent()
      .find(FormContextConsumer)
      .dive()
      .find(Footer).length
  ).toBe(1);
});
```

but when I destructure the context props like this:

```
    <FormContextConsumer>
      {({ handleSubmit, handleReset }) => (
        <Drawer
          ...
        >
          {children}
        </BaseEntityDrawer>
      )}
    </FormContextConsumer>
```

and test with this:

```
  it(`should always render 'Drawer' inside 'FormContextConsumer'`, () => {
    expect(
      shallowTestComponent()
        .find(FormContextConsumer)
        .dive()
        .find(Drawer).length
    ).toBe(1);
  });
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `handleSubmit` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

I'm assuming it has to do with how I'm mocking the module, but I'm not clear on how to adapt it to this case. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out thanks to stephenwil's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152120/5858391

I changed my mocked context to:

```
jest.mock("../../../forms/context/FormContext", () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  const handleReset = jest.fn();

  return {
    FormContextConsumer: props => props.children({ handleSubmit, handleReset })
  };
});
```

and my tests are working!